# An SDK Target must be specified error with android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-1.6

I have just put the first step in android,and just started with hello android example of android http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html. Now the problem is that when i navigate to /tools directory and execute the command `android create avd --target 2 --name my_avd` ,it gives error like :

mac123:android-sdk-mac_86 mac1$ android create avd --target 2 --name my_av
    -bash: android: command not found

Please mark that i am working with mac OS. Also is it any other way possible for the installation of the android SDK.

Kindly help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure know about mac os, but usually in unix-like systems the current directory is not in the PATH environment variable (a variable that tells your shell where to find executables). So to execute a command in your current directory you have to prepend `./`:

```
$ cd [android_sdk_dir]/tools
$ ./android create adv [...]
```

anyway consider beginning with eclipse, it eases a lot of tasks.

Comment: I tried to follow the path window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager in eclipse, but it is giving me error of no location found.So can't help myself. Any other way around?

Comment: @Sarah probably you're missing a step in SDK configuration: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#configuring

Comment: ya,I got the problem. I didn't follow the step to add the location through Eclipse->preference->android->sdk location.